# How to remove old polyline in google map flutter. I tried multiple ways like setting polyline to empty and clearing the list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

```
    setState(() {
      _marker = [];
      _mapMarkers = [];
      _markerInit = [];
      _polyLines = [];
      showPolygon = {};
      showCircles = {};
      polygon ={};
      circles ={};
      hideCircles ={};
      hidePolygon = {};

    });
```

I am resetting all objects before populating the data.

```
 return GoogleMap(
      onTap: (latLng) {
        if (isBottomSheetOpened) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          isBottomSheetOpened = false;
        }
        this.widget.expansionTile.currentState!.collapse();
      },
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) =>
          _onMapCreated(controller),
      mapType: trackingMapType,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      myLocationEnabled: false,
      mapToolbarEnabled: false,
      compassEnabled: false,
      circles: circles,
      polygons: polygon,
      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition!,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(_mapMarkers),
      polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_polyLines),
      onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        if (!isAnimationStarted) {
          setState(() {
            if (cameraPosition.zoom > 12) {
              _mapMarkers = _marker;
            } else {
              _mapMarkers = _markerInit;
            }
          });
        } else {
          if (_mapMarkers.length > 0) {
            int markerId = _markerIdVal();
            if (markerId < _mapMarkers.length) {
              Marker marker = _mapMarkers[_markerIdVal()];
              Marker updatedMarker = marker.copyWith(
                positionParam: cameraPosition.target,
              );
              setState(() {
                _mapMarkers[markerId] = updatedMarker;
              });
            }
          }
        }
      },
    );
```

How to remove old polyline in google map flutter. I tried multiple ways like setting polyline to empty and clearing the list

How to remove old polyline in google map flutter. I tried multiple ways like setting polyline to empty and clearing the list

I am drawing polyline using this method:

```
  for (TraceData traceData in traceResponse!.data!) {
          Marker marker = _getMarker(
              traceData,
              count,
              ((count == 0)
                  ? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
                  : (count == (traceResponse!.data!.length - 1))
                      ? BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
                          Uint8List.fromList(rotatedImage))
                      : markerList[traceData.vehStatus!.round()]),
              widget.vehicleDetails.isBS6!);

          if (count == 0 || count == traceResponse!.data!.length - 1) {
            _markerInit.add(marker);
          }
          _marker.add(marker);

          latLongs.add(LatLng(traceData.latitude!, traceData.longitude!));
          count++;
        }
        double kms =
            getDistanceInKm(latLongs[0], latLongs[latLongs.length - 1]);
        //("total distance $kms kms");
        setState(() {
          _mapMarkers = _markerInit;
          _loadPolyLine(latLongs);
        });
```

I have a button to clear polyline:

```
  void clearData() async{
    setState(() {
      _marker = [];
      _mapMarkers = [];
      _markerInit = [];
      _polyLines = [];
      showPolygon = {};
      showCircles = {};
      polygon ={};
      circles ={};
      hideCircles ={};
      hidePolygon = {};

    });
    
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by old polyline? Could you add a description of the workflow you're working with? How this polyline gets there and how it becomes old..

Comment: when ever data comes from api I am drawing a new polyline. But, before drawing new polyline I am removing previous polyline by using  _polyLines = [];. This not clearing the map or removing the polyline from the map. how can I get rid off the previous polyline.    latLongs.add(LatLng(traceData.latitude!, traceData.longitude!));
          count++;
        }
        double kms =
            getDistanceInKm(latLongs[0], latLongs[latLongs.length - 1]);
        //("total distance $kms kms");
        setState(() {
          _mapMarkers = _markerInit;
          _loadPolyLine(latLongs);

Comment: It seems the code you posted in the comment was trancated. Could you please rather add it to the question. Also two questions: I suppose that the first setState with all those initialisers are in a method which is called to "reset" the polyline. Where in the code is that method called? And do the rest of the variables reset?

Comment: I added code to the question. Yes, its in a method called cleardata. I am calling it on button tap. This button tap acts as a data range picker which gets new lat long for different data range

Comment: Sorry... I still can't see where you are calling `clearData()`. Ideally what you have provided should work so I can't make any further relation if I don't see where it's being used.

Comment: You might want to create a sample repo in github that reproduces the issue that we can clone and check ourselves what's wrong. That might be easier.

Comment: I upgraded the library to the latest now its working fine